# Android-Django user authentication

Tags: android, django, django-authentication

I am trying to access the current logged in user from the android app in django.
but the android application stops unexpectedly giving me fatal exception.
the android side code accepts json response when i comment the line

at django side i have this code ,

```
@login_required 
def add_healthrecord(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        if not request.user.is_authenticated(): # if user is not logged in
            response_data=[{"success": "0"}]
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data),mimetype='application/json')
        current_user=request.User
        response_data=[{"success": "1"}]
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/json')
```

can please somebody help me here.
actually i am trying to use user as foreign key thats why i need to access it.
the above django view give me response when i comment all the user related lines

Comment: in addition to Boris comment, you need to give us more about the problem. What is the fatal exception? What is the android side code? Are you passing the csrf token with any POST commands (for posts that require a valid login)?

Answer (score 1):

Without any more information, it seems like you're not passing the csrf token in with your post command. When using the `@login_required` decorator, you need to pass the csrf token (essentially the users session id) in with the request or you will not be able to post data to that view. Checkout the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users) for some more info.