# Android-Django user authentication-1

Tags: android, django, django-authentication

I am trying to refer user as foreign key in my django model AddRec(Having android at frontend)
at django side I have this code ,

**this is django model,**

```
class AddRec(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User)
     about=models.CharField(User)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class AddRecForm(ModelForm):
class Meta: 
    model=AddRec

@login_required 
def add_record(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        if not request.user.is_authenticated(): # if user is not logged in
            response_data=[{"success": "0"}]
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data),mimetype='application/json')
    current_user=request.User
    description=request.POST['about']
    new_rec = AddRec(user=current_user,about=description)
    new_rec.save()
    response_data=[{"success": "1"}]
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        response_data=[{"success": "0"}]
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data),mimetype='application/json')
```

When I execute the code above with Android as backend it gives me error "fatal exception".
The main thing is that I am not able to access the request the user sent from Android in django.

From the Android side I just send data with

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("about", "123"));
```

and with httppost I am sending data.
Is it necessary to send user name from the Android side even if the user is logged in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android-Django user authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851972/android-django-user-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

The authentication you are using stores session key in a cookie on the client side (android).  Are you using `HttpClient`? if so you must use cookies.

Additionally, api's should be stateless.  You should not be keeping a user logged in using cookies for an api. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer  There are a couple popular api authentication schemes that address this.

Are you sending csrf token with the request? If not you can explicitly disable csrf protection for your view using a decorator. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt (not recommended)

When posting a question please post error logs, tracebacks, basically everything you see when something doesn't go right.